# The identity function in several variables?

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus

The identity function in [one variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idenctitity_function), $id: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is given by $id(x)=x$.

Which are the corresponding identity functions for multivariable and vector-valued functions?

Comment: What do you think it could be?

Comment: HInt: $id(x)=x=1 \cdot x$

Comment: The question doesn't make sense. What do you mean by an identity function "for (any kind of) a function"? There is a unique identity function defined on any set $A$. It is the function $\operatorname{Id}_A:A\to A$ with $\operatorname{Id}_A(x)=x$ for each $x\in A$. It doesn't matter if $A$ happens to be a set of vectors, etc.

Answer (score 2):

The identity function on any set $X$, has domain and codomain $X$, and is defined as $f(x) = x$. Here, we are not worried about how many variables we are incorporating in $x$ e.g. if $X = X_1 \times X_2 \times ... \times X_n$ then we need to actually define $f(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$, but then treat $x = (x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$, and the identity function $f(x) =x$, so that $f(x_1,...,x_n) = (x_1 , ..., x_n)$ is the identity function for $n$ variables. In fact, $X$ could be the direct product of uncountably many spaces, and $f$ could depend upon uncountably many variables, but the definition remains one and only one : $f(x) = x$. So each variable gets mapped to itself.

It does not matter what $X$ consists of, either. Whether it consists of multivariable functions, vector-valued functions, projection valued measures, blue coloured balls, soft mattresses or Hindi movies, the function simply takes each function to itself, each projection valued measure to itself, each blue coloured ball to itself, each soft mattress to itself and each Hindi movie to itself. I repeat itself to remind you that the identity is defined almost independently of what the set $X$ is.